# Contar letras 'a' de um arquivo, usando egrep e wc

Tags: linux

Estou fazendo um estudo dirigido sobre sistemas operacionais, e travei nessa questão:

> 4) Utilizando o programa egrep em conjunto com o programa `wc`, conte
>   quantas letras "a" existem no arquivo mensagens.txt .

achei que fosse dessa forma:

```
egrep "a" mensagens.txt | wc -c
```

mas não é, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o parâmetro para egrep `-o` que, segundo o man:

`Prints only the matching part of the lines.`

Vai imprimir apenas a parte que se encaixou no padrão descrito por você.
Isso também resolve o problema de que caso um padrão apareça múltiplas vezes em uma mesma linha, o resultado do grep ser apenas uma linha. Isto é, utilizando este parâmetro, o comando grep irá ter como saída uma linha para cada match, e essas linhas não conterão nada além do match em si.

Concatenando com o `wc`, utilizamos o parâmetro `-l`, que segundo o man:

`The number of lines in each input file is written to the standard output.`

Simplesmente faz contar o número de linhas no input.

Comando final:

`egrep -o "a" mensagens.txt | wc -l`

Comment: vlw, foi certinho